# How to update a document in MongoDB and then remove the same update after a set time?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, settimeout

Here's what I've tried:

```
const addToFeatured = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { email: req.user.email },
    {
      featuredMember: true,
    },
    { new: true }
  );

  setTimeout(() => {
    const removeFromFeatured = User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { email: req.user.email },
      {
        featuredMember: false,
      }
    );
  }, 60 * 1000);
```

The first block of code is running as expected however the callback is not being run.
Ideally I would like the callback to fire after a period of two weeks, just using a minute for now for test purposes.

Comment: Even if this worked it's not a good way to do this. What happens if the server needs to restart - it won't "remember" the timeout's. I would suggest code that a) stores the date the user should be removed from featured in the database, and b) periodically checks the `User`s and sets `featuredMember` to false once the above date is reached

Comment: ... or `featuredMember: date_two_weeks_from_now` ... then the part of your code that determines featured members, rather than looking for `featuredMember === true` just needs to check for `featuredMember > new Date` ... no need for timeouts or periodic cleaning